# Borrar datos de un bucle en PHP

Tags: php

Logro borrar datos pero solo cuando hay 2 cosas en el bucle. Cuando hay más de 2 solo borra de 2 en 2 y no se porqué.

```
<?php
session_start();


if(isset($_GET['p'])){
$_SESSION['producto'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['p']; 
$_SESSION['contador']++;


}

if (isset($_GET['c'])){
$_SESSION['cantidad'][$_SESSION['contador']] = $_GET['c'];
}

include '../conexion/server.php';
$suma = 0;
for ($i=0; $i < $_SESSION['contador']; ++$i){
//echo "producto:".$_SESSION['producto'][$i]."-".$_GET['c'][$i]."<br>";

    $query = mysqli_query($conect,'SELECT * FROM Productos WHERE 
    id='.$_SESSION['producto'][$i].'');

    while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_array($query)) {


        $cab = $_SESSION['cantidad'][$i+1];
        $total = $fila['Precio']*$cab;
            echo '<tr>';
            echo '<td>'.$fila['Nombre'].'</td>';
            echo'<td></td>';
            echo '<center><td>';
            echo '<center><input type=number name=ja class="las ma" 
   value='.$cab.'></center>';
            echo '</td></center>';
            echo '<td>$'.$fila['Precio'].'</td>';
            echo '<td>'.$i.'</td>';
            echo '<td>$'.number_format($total,2).'</td>';
            echo '<td>';
            echo '<input type=hidden value='.$_SESSION['contador'].' 
            class=jk>';
            echo '<a href=functions/checkout.php?a='.$i.' 
            class=borrar>Borrar</a>';

            echo '</td>';
            echo '</tr>';

                $suma += $total;                                            
    }

    if(isset($_GET['a'])){

                    unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);

                    $_SESSION["producto"] = 
  array_values($_SESSION["producto"]);

                        $_SESSION['contador'] -=1;
                }
 }

 echo '<tr><th colspan="5">Total</th><th 
colspan="2">$'.number_format($suma,2).'</th></tr>';
mysqli_close($conect);

 ?>
```

Comment: Revisa [ask] por favor Jose, que deseas realizar, se mas especifico por favor.

Comment: Si organizaras algo mejor tu código y dijeras lo que pretendes hacer con él quizá se te podría ayudar mejor, por ejemplo al ver esto: `$_SESSION['contador'] -=1;`  me pregunto lo que quieres hacer ahí.

Comment: veras viene de otra pagina donde $_SESSION['contador'] = 0; y es el que da el index del array, tengo botones que pasan el id y que viene con GET con al variable 'p' como esta arriba....cada vez que doy click contador ahce aumentar un campo en el bucle y si no pongo $_SESSION['contador'] -=1; me sale error del offset=0 peor ahora no em sale eso pero despues de 2 valores me empieza a borrar de 2 en 2 solo cuando tengo 2 valores me borrar 1 y no se poque

Comment: puedes editar tu pregunta [aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/110266/edit)

Comment: Verifica tu ciclo tal ves te sea mas conveniente usar en el for $i++ y no al reves (++$i)

Comment: ya le cambie y me sigue dando el mismo problema.....

Comment: logre hacer que se borren de abajo hacia arriba pero si tomo los de la mitad se borran de 2 en 2

Comment: if(isset($_GET['a'])){
          echo '<script> window.location="../carrito.php";</script>'; 
           unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);
     $_SESSION["producto"] = array_values($_SESSION["producto"]);
  if($_GET['a'] == 0){
  $_SESSION['contador'] = 0;
      }

     }

Comment: if(isset($_GET['a'])){
          echo '<script> window.location="../carrito.php";</script>'; 
           unset($_SESSION['producto'][$_GET['a']]);
     $_SESSION["producto"] = array_values($_SESSION["producto"]);
  if($_GET['a'] == 0){
  $_SESSION['contador'] = 0;
      }

     }